ACUMATICA Custom Field Not Showing on ADD DATA FIELDS CUSTOM Field Names list
I need to add a Custom Field to the Checks and Payments Screen (AP302000), APPLICATION HISTORY Tab grid.
When I add the new field, this is included in two Data Access,  "APTranPostBalExtensions", and "APTranPostExtensions". After publishing, the field does not show in the "ADD DATA FIELDS"/"CUSTOM" Field Name.
Any Help is appreciated.
Thanks!!





Using the Customization Project Editor UI I was successfully able to create a new custom field, which extended the Data Access Classes, and the field is available to select for the Application History tab:

Here is the xml from my project to compare with your code.
<Customization level="" description="AP302000 Cross Rate" product-version="24.107">
    <Page path="~/pages/ap/ap302000.aspx" pageSource="7T39U+Q2sj+TqvwPurlLdnO3y7BsNpeDIfUG2A9eYJkHZDevrq4oMSPAWWNPbA8Ludv3t79ufdiSJcvyfJDk6lJJAFvqbrVare5Wqz344r/IiF4xckiTqxn8stPb+2OPHNG8YBm+eBXF8Oz/+tWTvP8qzW72WUGjeP2GP+6R4axIX96ypHgfZWw23ekV2Yz1yDsaRxNasBP284zlxU7vksY5PN9LJxLycPR8Y3NjY2Od5tO79XHeIwfJNcuiIt/pIbZz1aBHzqICe/yQFPjLhNPdI1989/lnn382gHEIEs/up4y8i7JiRuMRLa4DiEcQA8C/tZcmBYyBHOzv9Mbw+zOklD8axXTM3qTxhGX4cnq9f9oj2SyhMKZTlt0CGACyNpjebY1+3KcFPU1n2ZiRlwm9iNmwKLLoYlawXDEGgUzyEkQuQJAf9l8h/a8iFk92evvpGP8CNkZ5dIFjP+Od30cTHNezjY0vgCvQ4i29gZejH9ePL35i4yJfH47g3xG9vwHSXyZFdt8joyy6odn9u4h95JBn+I4TvTbYo3F8Qccf9tKbG5pMcv5UDea09pYIbAcJEF0A3DQvcMDIh/iyR/r+zvgzKvauQdyQG2JAAuIpvWWt/UXTV1GWO3CfFjQr3rKPr7MUZVAADwJ4SF3wWro60Ql4JyxmVEi6Y7xBJL1Lo8neNRt/mA+Ih7jhuIjSxAJbhNN2kPw8i1Cq5gdxwqYpys88EMr18EqoEwERBvuOJZM0m7P/y0lULARAdFZrK58XCqzQ4yy6ihIal+t0bki7tBhfh1NyWe//Lp2NQR93BGORMRrtvxueDSc/9cg+mwKfjpPXWQQ6bsKKK/hlM3iEFoXv0+zDbpp+6EydRxUdpnRykNym0Zh1n8YWuKPj4wy2kQ5wL51wC0PdwPaRs+F0GkdjKlZ3A5/nFwUNeimXy8eiQJ+liO++AcMCCPZmWQbwpUQvSr8h6QL0mG+ygWoQtuWkkGoeOxDtnzn2UHgFk0STMVN8/NMIDJFr2Iu41P3pMEo+9CzumFwIYnA3Ik5nF2hQZXRcLI+ERmxy6R7sB+Ka2DDyRbZuB0m7URz/lugZTrnQ/aZIyqTF+lsiapSlaFKfZTTJKbebfjXqhpNJxvL8EPa62RQMVCDLa8nV6euOBCxqjgadoCyN84N9AH4JDlSPgPlGUXPJN2B9pQmzHvMOk/zJCQPyCuTEuUTQieZB3+WhDPo1bwvduL7mxzW5dZvNbt2rZq8OHUdU7ByMYELNezst7pH0X55GyYTdbZFn6LUazhrSesRuLlim+WBkj05xGtHh5fJPTmc36KuBPk0LdpBMcNdNMyUs6Djn1lMUhduouG98IZ1KBKke9ZC5KMxWp90R9+ZtNC9vwHOOkqvXGZ1eGz7n3gn8y18r8EcoCk+qJrhELuksVuKBjGST0ss9oxcHyLid3uY3nHVHNPuAkYMoY+gN3yf0JhpLl/WMwdqiBdNl+pDep7PiZBYze2bAGdpL49lNogZySC9YnMvZORUSATSdRr8w/re5WrJ0up9+TEiN5BoanN66727AEcspzSScE3b59iLzgVEtML4Cv8PKuZYDEGDXBqhtQElNwRmPWE5egSMLAlKwjEPIMcIixer8/OVdIQA+IcJXOdivfjsXv5zT8bhAXfCEDEdyIz0/l7/wrjC0fZaPq6H1jbF5+AbTUMzsqIc2XtVCxE0mpX1lzgbM+1l0w9Bhc+tTgQ7cDWzqw1c2cU+TH/irKBmxLEonB/stOIyW9lwayM/YXdE2snIifXi1Rv3VLJMfjyzGXaGkHdH8g498JXI+6qs2wzhOP8K28RYjV1Kn4SNkUvlA52lh8bQTXYepcHIc9NlTZ5Osd3dPrED23yloR1iajPkZIYRRb7+Oy1NbI679PUSEpV44YsV1mwxbTR2cmIfjezS/Ho7H6QytPh8BtYZe9BTwK1fsBFa3AWeW3SMAiX6Gu2wNK3ZB3S1CpQrQQXKZmhv4uXp17tNPcsdg0zSPiuElDzh7tg2jndshbF6/YumeTiks37oPW5O+Uol7tzBTzy+oPY6atYcG/+0MudumAHHiMEgGNA5vCq/g1Foag9GQVXBHxxh5CACrNfTuV04sPyQU4ylsskvjNkRm2+64DpKogPEHYNJbtnsqTmSBzFuAdUBSdsUCcGgNXVjUqurrxqS0ZpS1H+pTPG/2KV43+xRg8nIIBb2wxvKGRVfX8PfzjY3pndO52PZ4FzLKVTvoOSjYjXG6gzY3PCOoHSqXJCdFSmT4TXp0x8k+Q8+r3G2U/Wka4gouWqXikEvF61pG9yFKsLk4mQO34ww54h5z5Sc833hhuVimxnT8g8eAQgFxJ4ObEvAMfBrTsoahHLJbUF/l39rY+BuD4WDlzfJCOPlVj7XBSfqxzqIKlE+V1zSlaYgdOdVt38ZQs8CByhDvxWjm0wM6qppzgzAajFTH7u1EUqNIQtMxrw1GNANrCLbL3HguaZJs5I2I5nYK/12GPJSDtH5b2pzSo7oXLZAOFdL4+5c/z9JiuzJixd//WH9HY4sxbWSUq0NRIqRoner8t2nhqBQl2lxJUupEDPpuJjkdt5YZPYwStsQpLcEtY1JXxU38A13TDHTEEidYLY4AikTTBoJkUIV32umRpc2+e3ef/HTl2nnbJtvo61AejchGo30XPq62387iuNzRHchU3y743l+f0btFRlgBcKlj2zWQEhcQqaiaNdhMbZiqeM7+jLUidLTujifK20fmau7AtPrN0hIKZDrO64lrCCH6reocKoNhdrpqFSAIbizA6BA0qtm8ePhiCEBUtfNhGvTd1tRAzGxuE4W2mnhZn5ndjCbja9zrT2AjF4SnmbCDGwWkGVwVxea6WZldhxHmFeHmiCcYu3T8IQy6q4fbGiIYv5fHIg0n6AujKnfpPk+2C2PKCM/MeOQYaElF1CWcpbK3PH7r2LfUJ/N1F6jPaP5hro57aV5gguNcnbUYVxuzWybO2HFRrodxdAXa7wQdrwWFor7Brgh8tZV2RdC0cc4jRL7dr72zb0frtgqrvWQBbuibx6Jg1OawIJxK9y8yyxrLa3HLMBFRgeFOnYxznXlorc7V5ut/OpOBwfvqvATmBTbI+yNQQTu9N5HMHmyJimjxZTfSNzR/eTfFo1hnWoPY9nhOyW56t6C0nxazC4slg769yw+ETUhUtE5FlYye0tEpwzZVfKdfC/AMkC60IisrRNB2FCUK9LMXGzr0gUjB2KWaAzXYAxcvvdGCbRoXztIUhp3tzooiTWTcDdMCScVMg3U6q0i5z5sJimcY5ix4Rrnp+u2ya3obNZ0CmXPU1zEZfLfpDhqV8CwJP7ci/OAqZGTDiXbS9asODQTOMY8ArD7jmoCpqGi/lp/Q16OtzQFYlRnaEHTtFnP9+uGCrqf3yXiEB1c8jaWYP4o6Ov6txFHD9WUZYvUdteK4Jnx6nbFXbzhD69aNsqBD4IqylnwCs5194q6fyisRCKGV02vEqEJ7VSNtib99rQJwSr54AE7ja0AMrmxtRFmDyex3HmF4eLZtemHAnmh8g1/5O5/g4RJC6MEkBodYwwdcO6+XtwbA4mvNobKaes4+Awix4jqjY18g2BfzXQpSzKRmk0DUWuOOSt0Oa2qasi2kWU6B1vqhAluaVvPdreoAjKuDxWEpxbIYJEu6O/maviMIf6+aJHWjVROD7p1FBsg0Q5twcpYW6CnPBwXjeAsB6OTmyjuQk67OoQbiIJc3h/0w/t1dQ+UWYIMimppPA73F6trZ78GlWhtg+IJgOtJb9hGUo6Unlud0affayJsox1j1stJeNufI6qm7Vi4nrXUnE0ZQleqCs+XKdSGSfK1r7c5B4bxzwJ+6+5ZBKkHD5vk5PkVWSzDuBvzVvLk3I7y5bbiLXHyMzGG57fJn+6CaCubeirtuuaMTdhVhIYHz8yWeKfHrie7zHfMCYzBEcUfGe07VEVbjCZTzpmgw8IbTpso2m/PAKRTAfIdGlRQ09A9F7zp3Cu3bdPQU2r/D6VPdRFrwlIbn0855muQ6T1gU0JyRfU3wux4ZVQL02z+tqnF8l8Z4HODhebjj1Xre1IJpLm53PC7Senc/NtI6/1rHR+XGCwvl4U6guhI3AnhgqYBWMOZ6D7Q7WlJzOxU6ClWWAiUgi6biNq21n2nVK7j5IC7YlTYhf3aaZmV9o2VIvEblAkdvHbCEHro9vM8knhn+EtYK8kdUhNnnbyPMQH+bU0az8bW/Ddp5J2ycZhN/O7RzT69TL1XKGdI53tVplOVAiF4PJMBNdFUR+T04i8tzBUEhw+KKaNxy1LbAFUrXLSheo6m8Bf76kIgCAxyWq5ZVSUctQbtyGppDk1WbuhBalyrr2KygrNTz4VeMGjrUKLFHGXSXsPK+PKMv2/iQqDTWoJuJRrOWxdCM6nR20YZGNmm++lgiMILXHo4FpB07bNGQw6fyGr1AFHhTusEekidAcoNrQAhmCC9cgYtNH+X4+sNeDDqc2XeQdPtSNZmXlRxAGzO1Rt1GJweibofm0vdvv0eaW1GCGjoTsp9JWiMvm4wrr60Cpjdr3hed+k72bdF4eiuPztNvjVfbg3kKhxdJ209R9VZtSlbb7jSzU992iWGKNlWG0zY5SfJcO1Yx14519mLj2bdEVfTTty0VtHULX40SKYsHyTieTdhBwsEqqPqpgLMBdw8O2WWhh4oXjgxn6S1MXI/sRtwZ4Xc88ZVRBWfOPB2MECsUTnkSYTZVK7Q9LOyuFyNjzDGwZotsbJMineJPLdbaZKdrstUpnsqf/TCdUGeMtVtoV/FnkRAthwGWC8xGes8Yj3MVex0DOw4Qog5DMBCsVHiF66JrTAlRg4O9OP0WkI4jQO1z/DFh3Muv12rCJLCGmlPBBHYMPqkzYDt9yiWCCwflTxjN0Snyy3fbSPMcFJUwALkkhDAynETQ8EufnNOCTZcOdC9jwL+Jshy6Q18kNrE8l7EqbTa3z7jY9TUB3ahOppVbQ9h07LjNqPbuqi0p2+oK2AVLLCS5r/DpzJl2/GYxYNUsaLJqjwE2zDBrZELLDT6rv9PLsMioGY2vQC8JPevxfMo2bdCGBRaZ4LEZj7NYNbLgodupZzVdpwl75k1mki0ckKJYg8Rrvzl5DKaRacpo0GUv3Yy11o9VkiNA8Ms6gwGCX7ZtEPzy/e9N8BuZECj4Zf8wwZdBSCTiokhqpSTdcuGsOumUGcGiu1zPRX/qEsv6gpGwoxYxN9t1gGonebihbrZD3cOijL4AAn9vQam5xXsYjRLHUp3ql2n92nL0nHjRGnOktntxyj6tWirNCxrj0XZnWda7+hcOmxzk6osV3kCI0cwTs+imyTQlgdToD2zBNR1wXkWaHPO/clfguN2ACApA6dWqPRuG1kqs2iMLXU10LjBMJcuwtAdYdh2tg6PZ8xp6ophU8+Wcjqlhzx/sds58jrdkbzlqfPc94xn0eVne9IksJ6pSdnTr3Hthpzb9/BslCDBMZ7UteQOcwyFxBOCDIv1VI4+0NfuDNtrWqL9sMBc6Z0EGzPMJqG5SuK5kl32Xlrrecg+0bR7djiWS2TWjo/EEp2N2upyvTtkzJVvthJa2whEPfDw/h9dspzvUtGqZ0eC6TaTrUn8ChSuW3FSC3Qik1rQu8uQ1S1gGSCVveXAKDH9XTPZ7xqbVxUe51xqXIeUzpzJ35ONq1ek2fferKl0elmBiK3gXa1rAcZCVxLU1NSmwhZ8ntWjJck61ri0KDO4vJ52sLJHiL3C3KBoe4iqHt5KRqAjoysagCrDbeUaOnKzlIByz6PZXQLjCWTrIR1k6Bj/wAYcFTkoKLvxDIpQhXdShNyD4Y9i57h8M/SmWO13dFGpZ3UZ+YKVGeaagaLUk9QGeq8oG9+BUzVaqBG5ZMmMBxGgtV6lYtTz3Fs4Ix391lPAUNXEg5kTiI0/2XS4lIoy8kjVQZfh6RqU+obcylgsEYpgGHSsatfh0U+OY3Z94cruoel60uBG1LAKHN+jArCr9XvOPLBbXRrokhJn1xYGVydNw+oC4qm9ctQuU/UEshwA9nNG8h5+YucTcEiZCC6vCI6yI3fJexaIA0So4yPMZt4VWQfHLy0uG3zxiqzQhk3yGyasMBYUm9ytDw+91rFadlN/na18D9U/5PaRePVDXLh7QhFbuFq+BJWPoD4Sco1ztxHMU5beRVyLAOooHdyU5cmklIdSExgcTr7Wk9VglQwSGl3eCphWaiPghbViHsE8sU4MfRix5T2Eqs9XK52EEymVVwIV5ccpq5C+P9+U3PQNMi9rnP39dwwJJWalJIe2oVYYH0jgar2pTdn2EtH2OPZ8uDd1FVzMa/YPEeHKIxwGrCo9W3x0OF/I2xtofM14yqStmihiuKO0kV52DNW1csKD4ZGvpcuNgzbKm1/XB7CXGmVeohJS9s7sqRXTKQEQnNLsPigTVWq9QNGqYVmjfiOM/WUJlJQimaZKn2XF2RZPoF3ULdxWYzq6zdHZ13SCPrrla9tGb/GTS3GKhH3+3tjXTFMKHoWdteDLztIi0I2NFJeaJRptdJ7BMl/Fe1KzztZEOR9ul06OipqJWwu79MI5Fwqzzk63GPV7Zc+kkaWGH7lRpnZdOmGa4dydM67x8wvRw5Ryk6d2XTpzbKu5OpRvO8sk1zZc56DQBLGEz7Up1ZZeGEVm1XzpdhmHfhZeeO9wGzFVSHMBHZ+ul0+TwBJo3L7vt8unRTry7LxC999JJqx2Bd6euBmA5BBoajJdecmYsdKE2zPAKt6YcCYnNTVuz2uy6oO1Ud0p0bASCeZgXdKycndbUO6QRCOyup8GqtVGplM1llJQFfUJkImJIWSDTqVMdyW/1oyMFGeYEC/nEofXpG8YNoIa5AGTUYwhbID76QyobeaDK/Fv7rWdFDmqMdoJvnzkbpweu42bFoF+N2bWikA2y4paTBrzMgyoOQ7pXlTQNpA7r0qlhmVXKgt/6hLWS7fTeR8kk/djz6Y9vVaJ0NWrJDqnBb2hWjGjCYq60p/ibuk/edEXxJZ4hEdVKPi6vRMtaHSmdVFdRxLPv2b26rC7v1Z8w3Ar4VwpyrNurz9rTclRFuSeU77TiYJzDSIZ4hYr4qZPfMr/6G55RDciMHvXJGI7HbFqIFSIvDgrKjzGWiFondrwUL2QG9QnLeca0vAohNzV+SUf7GI3jumj158gzHXbWd30mtE+2VLdHm7gvZV98LJ5f5yG7XAhjUbIDvJApzfgp0W6aVddN36YJa8hdF3+RvTzfi2kuk3B4aefaZaTWi2Y+PjTfIRNgK+GWvzfAMS7RnkZAn3Z5qo3AcNq8V1adty89818rAIEdRZz5aBYXEe6o8uaunJ+NanI2xcUCY1F4t0apQDgLA/grVod9x1ddOVDvjZGbN3WrBVeDIb9K9T0G12mcXsFKg/Hu9P6XVXWJzKXRb0Wjlq4TlXpponub+rFZHDOvpdi3LtWHWUqd7FPVJa+xbkdjvR77Yt6322Qqr4FsEXqRg3QWbJuIOjybf53eyVI8f/sb/CpLumu30wU+UiI0GpSq56xxExBaMIY31ragD0S4BhL6IttCnOZMzLc5ecMLLM/0HdZiqlhsqGGspdTK37pydYzBoalb6+tXFouH9U0KXy0xXWlrNlDT7aW2mgCtNSRrZQOObNus5jVqKuwtL8/Oixl5gyFGu/YrmW4CykvFehT2KkkzpmDnWDrqisqLy767x75+Nfp0Yiyr2NYG8vkkuiW5kJcpnWC1L5SX6Z343wvxH6xZUFRPKR6VbJEMVfy2MecNek8XV9SnTu2nGtb1H3T4TpJduhJdEDaoXBOJamQqYrmAQCNeRclTobteTO8qHg/6wDfOxO5K1fwuSZMVbHwCpaMRzF+IrrgvBOs35e8JOTHpXNQ+RkJ8JrHYwZqsVS/P5jJVNR7J7fSBjFPrqvyiivHHmmI8rdsj9Xq5c1WMFaD27YqXr7L0Zr+l3GXVxksZH2nIRxlrDU2g1g3wI3onnh1favdhm6G72/dLnWlrfF51AjW+YeWfpLNkIgRGXs2dylOMpkXPX5OL+4ZP3Wg08paY8SCFQFzkbQpxBAQt26TwiIFucMqfq1KmN9LHMZ3QSZRKBe4I72aoI7QPiPEDW1hWpXXOOYXvnggtSUAS1peKmIuWxLtp4vXj8oek+obEfFdW61y1FnAs3bO0beGqFt5l+zIJ+pKq0az0YQxl6KoUs0Q38GG8wId0Aus+oG2NrOHTLz7/bPTj+vEFBmTy9b3T9dGPRvGpdfV1jr04wi2QfxXicXEd5U/IJF/HSXyd0en1V9uff/aFMHtc5o0Bkz+2xgrULOozEh5ckxpToiSyiBa8kuvhry/QzVnbZ5cUGKl9OzXngVbMh4fX13K7/vprGbWzbIkKWc37hBfc2DIGrXwy3suM4sl2L5MiKu53CyUMGJbUw3mFNJbwiwmwEUU38FQA0RDbsT5EyOfuJX4HKn86vAQ6EMZOj+oEDkcH61ECrAZb/hd2RKe51XWXgWvK3kQY6LH6jrGYt4hV46IacNcBflm/jNnd07EKHpN/AtSJSE3cIvhum/T/TEBlREkMDZ7iI/LnPrTiHSdRxsZi/sdcx22Xk8Pd1y/g708KS4SFNP4pHtzQaRmxfkL+KOmlwJ8xHuAwaEqnSIzuDG9IaGN+HvGW3u5SQXEphaUQwkMueugN4R9CJtVfBtBnEuqUjmuMaG+2RXG+eGNgE37zJ6agq7MtkqQFSRibsAmsAZLjdzQeTdOPLIMHF/fkdZpexewRiS4J2LgpofIJgaklUc47JJzRABrD/liKN5k8jW7A6EboCSN/iG6wmDRNCp3rYoif0MNRkzwQn4shBd4reYQuYf8nekvF00fQ4Bb4aIjMO5rlZIc8vpwlfHrJ46/4ILHhuViJ/zNj2T206fUQe8aKWZbwNms5K06rJiBGJZBbgCI/4leDcrvNH396gj+uGgFU/SVCHYwEAf+H/z599Ri1nmNsQu9pgxNjQ5FWeM6hwxtwgyYxU8cuj8eimPYTwrIszQQ71mD61Auys0OSWRyTf/2LyEewYi9T9fwrTp0ge1tYDw5unr82xs7HINA8xtlLL2sddsgjEAt2CcI4efQV4OZYHtcbcQIa3/Z65bv6K0sq1q9qBEpOrNktTTkwsIphrVlqClQPurkHwDdxipVLDlSMEzM8DzoL2xUDbTNhDe0/1WQCZgYNHFoUZUHFx6UYPF77w+Pp3TkIS74uqICNAZNjmV6pEZnHLVPo+BchyK2dNo1Onj5YbjG0LS9kGExNVZRQ68LlWU2+XI0oZmqK8IdapA7WvWHxlGWPee/eE9LjC3/t72Jxd+Lkk8A+m6F9aoyUbdsGAcOAUahPlP5dnZOH8b/s12UGZJd/iJ8tYxLVMuu9ed9QaZejzcGAybBk/xNCs6tcigDqsowbv+WesIav18EoeUnH14JJpcqFV0p2uHaDv8kfpAL98ksi/0TFJBvxVhJB7c1aiVf+8hdS0rgt23ySP+2mgEo2Em0+CWUhRVc0a2CQoQcrNuDuke2CZZ4kUXIllbpXdDTJUYIzzxKYaw10WgSh4uxt7RFmIctfyf0R1Gqdl9Uea7+pZEJOnhTDT11UUU0TmViWu8TwAzuJCYN3LLeVABmY8br+Ah+Mfzuo2+Z83Z536MbFJ7y5EKDw9odpchUVs4mzj+CzbpHa5tyWy8bj09soIFse4Wnq6e7DWzfO/pZHMgzbFgx8bsELxx4PhMYiZm36dCJdwXof8SRdeYSknIcouWZZVKjPreiddI+tR6IJf6IhaQRVZksgMOj3qPTkS3iPFBLdsyuJc8QY0LfjzpwINvBf+fHWFk9g2CY39O7pR4wobJFvVIh1rYqElUcVtkdOfKEH0hAvwUPhpvLlrtAE/6fDOa3qop+EuAIYVXpeU3F3I4tEG5gzAUVOgGQk9+e94X0OTvFBz4DUAxU8H1bEMRyBigsw+4daGEDAlJNh1sR2f0HKOVDTW4CJb/vEQdWm/532aWkH6GblvKz67c16fFm13JtVfiCG590wzFk53gdRbL5eoFXB+C6Q3XXia0UtWTeYngLxxi19Ty14D/RDWvC90Qe7atMJstp2vaCrRhXs0Ory6oBe3zDU6q1FB+ubl1BP32kQyl+rX5y7oPO8oh73LbML1AaHoWdbHZIyNG3URfccaDR/W0Kc14g864bjBGs7Mvs4TyxEk4aMCsV7Q2PDH1jS2VLWl3j5MSk3PjPBTc8jt85WGqLqS0z62JYPhFnAnzSfvgjxqH7auSFrTScnvGLNiN4z5j45UZkF3xiZld++EJmV6jxEzAnhwAiHZmdDnFWZInjr9H1UXFfI2zI9qhNNd1rJWXNayfCWRjE2q7DlmNXvy+Sr5TObR7lGoogLujqO8WTV2RxQnYyz/Ldoelt3K3wH661Jvfa+Xs9vC/0qjht17ZS2/QMTqoWR6Fa47g8W7uw317m3rZ5NKssvRDRLR8NC2PxaXwgi4caRC2nWIK8XKq8LFifMvjnVMODGi1vV2OwS5I4115RI0H7R318fAgUAC4FJY7x6UK8Mxo8g+Z9D/Jyge7iheJUczdtffVdjbgCVwT1Pb/w6gVYV7vij69O/QV1HNOrUdZfG/JsAmCrm/qcp4aRZUFouIjZcPhz4LmXJl01iORDfSiVHLJnVfVJ5Naz+uDGTRnxiNQjUWTr1AMJvxOJx+KJUqetqFsMar7Et5yOyjunU8dSNzkq3yD3FbVM4rEqDdEcmi2GpNBiG0Mb+1JneqzmlJQA9z7kPoYF8KfLzHYnFJAhZGyavVSkwq5VszaCRKxxsJ2qFm/h+1sVUfLFhmorGjVifkVhH2poNvICNWMe1kH1Y2hZuqP9mdoU9TasxK+RXsH7H9gG4nKKuzfk5brsikkNIyDZtbuxOzP/Zo/+zR4fs0fJ32w2cY1fmu01dATzofjXo03y6Je9QwN//Dw==" />
    <Table TableName="APTranPost">
        <Column TableName="APTranPost" ColumnName="UsrAdjdCuryRate" ColumnType="decimal" AllowNull="True" MaxLength="19" DecimalPrecision="8" DecimalLength="19" IsNewColumn="True" IsUnicode="True" />
    </Table>
    <DAC type="PX.Objects.AP.APTranPost">
        <Field FieldName="UsrAdjdCuryRate" TypeName="decimal" MapDbTable="APTranPost" TextAttributes="#CDATA" StorageName="AddColumn">
            <CDATA name="TextAttributes"><![CDATA[[PXDBDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Cross Rate")]
]]></CDATA>
        </Field>
    </DAC>
    <DAC type="PX.Objects.AP.APTranPostBal">
        <Field FieldName="UsrAdjdCuryRate" TypeName="decimal" MapDbTable="APTranPostBal" TextAttributes="#CDATA" StorageName="AddColumn">
            <CDATA name="TextAttributes"><![CDATA[[PXDBDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Cross Rate")]
]]></CDATA>
        </Field>
    </DAC>
</Customization>

